# Gluon: SettingsService is crashing on iOS

Tags: ios, settings, gluon, gluon-mobile

The SettingsService of Gluon is Crashing on our iOS device.

First, we implemented a View with Settings, where we read the settings from a previous stored file with a BufferedReader. This worked fine on android, but crashed on iOS.

**PresentationModel:**

```
  public void readSettings(String fileName) {
    if (!Objects.equals(null, checkFileExistence(directory, fileName, false))) {
      settingsFile = checkFileExistence(directory, fileName, false);
      // read line per line
      try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(settingsFile));
        setFirstName(br.readLine());
        setLastName(br.readLine());
        setAdress(br.readLine());
        setPlace(br.readLine());
        setPhoneNumber(br.readLine());
        setMailAdress(br.readLine());
        setPersonalInformation(Boolean.valueOf(br.readLine()));
        setConsultant(Boolean.valueOf(br.readLine()));
        // close BufferedReader
        br.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

**View:**

```
public void addBindings() {
    firstNameTxt.textProperty().bindBidirectional(pm.firstNameProperty());
    lastNameTxt.textProperty().bindBidirectional(pm.lastNameProperty());
    adressTxt.textProperty().bindBidirectional(pm.adressProperty());
    placeTxt.textProperty().bindBidirectional(pm.placeProperty());
    phoneNumberTxt.textProperty().bindBidirectional(pm.phoneNumberProperty());
    mailAdressTxt.textProperty().bindBidirectional(pm.mailAdressProperty());
    personalInformationSwitch.selectedProperty()
        .bindBidirectional(pm.personalInformationProperty());
    consultantSwitch.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(pm.consultantProperty());
  }
```

After that, we've discovered the SettingsService.

**We stored the keys with the values in Arrays:**

```
private String[] settingsKeys = {"firstName", "lastName", "adress", "place",
          "phoneNumber", "mailAdress"};

      private Property[] settingsProperties = {firstName, lastName, adress, place, phoneNumber,
          mailAdress};
```

**And read them like this:**

```
public void readSettingsService() {
    if (!com.gluonhq.charm.down.Platform.isDesktop()) {
      Services.get(SettingsService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
        // read all strings
        for (int i = 0; i < settingsKeys.length; i++) {
          settingsProperties[i].setValue(service.retrieve(settingsKeys[i]));
        }

        personalInformation.setValue(Boolean.valueOf(service.retrieve("personalInfo")));
        consultant.setValue(Boolean.valueOf(service.retrieve("consultant")));
      });
    }   }
```

Bindings in the View stay the same. Again, this is working perfectly fine on android, but crashes on iOS.

Another thing we tried, is to first set intial values to the Textinputfields and bind them afterwards to the settingsvalues. This also did not work on iOS.

The thing is, that our solutions work on android, but the app always crashes on iOS. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks for the help.

---EDIT---

**iOS stacktrace when opening the settings (it did not log anything in the device logs):**

```
2018-06-07 10:33:45.628332+0200 BodenDok[4508:1079080] firstName not found
2018-06-07 10:33:45.628688+0200 BodenDok[4508:1079080] lastName not found
2018-06-07 10:33:45.628847+0200 BodenDok[4508:1079080] adress not found
2018-06-07 10:33:45.628975+0200 BodenDok[4508:1079080] place not found
2018-06-07 10:33:45.629061+0200 BodenDok[4508:1079080] phoneNumber not found
2018-06-07 10:33:45.629136+0200 BodenDok[4508:1079080] mailAdress not found
2018-06-07 10:33:45.629340+0200 BodenDok[4508:1079080] Done retreiving personalInfo
2018-06-07 10:33:45.629495+0200 BodenDok[4508:1079080] Done retreiving consultant
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_de_CH'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_de_CH</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_de'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_de</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-min-height' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-min-width' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-width' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-height' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-min-height' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-min-width' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-width' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-height' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
setSwapInterval(1)
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-min-height' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-min-width' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-width' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-height' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-min-height' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-min-width' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-width' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
Jun 7, 2018 10:33:45 AM java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl log
WARNING: Could not resolve 'default' while resolving lookups for '-fx-pref-height' from rule '*.bottom-nav>*.button' in stylesheet jar:file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC6EB215-8FEF-4EF5-8FA5-A4A7CBD26C31/BodenDok.app/lib/classes43.jar!/ch/fhnw/style.css
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: FillRoundRect_LinearGradient_PAD.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: DrawRoundRect_Color.frag
PPSRenderer: scenario.effect - createShader: LinearConvolveShadow_64
Growing pool ES2 Vram Pool target to 101,466,116
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
AppLauncher failed with an exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: The app crashed: Terminated due to signal 11. Check the device logs in Xcode (Window->Devices) for more info.
  at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.pipeStdOut(AppLauncher.java:829)
  at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launchInternal(AppLauncher.java:734)
  at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launch(AppLauncher.java:1052)
  at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.AppLauncherProcess$1.run(AppLauncherProcess.java:67)
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

ext.checkstyleVersion    = '8.3'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'MainClassname'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx
    compile group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.14'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'compass', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'local-notifications', 'magnetometer', 'pictures', 'position', 'runtime-args', 'settings', 'share', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        compileSdkVersion = 25
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace you get on iOS. Also post your build.gradle file (at least with the Gluon related stuff). That will help to identify the root of the problem. `SettingsService` works fine on Desktop, Android and iOS, so probably something else is happening.

Comment: Updated the post. Hope it helps you.

Comment: What makes you think that the error is in the Setting service? Did you check the crash? (Open Xcode->Window->Devices and Simulators->Show logs)

Comment: Yes we checked that, but it did not log anything, as mentioned before.

It could be also possible that the binding does not work, which would be very strange, due to the fact that it is perfectly working on android.

Comment: Check again, it does log a crash report, and you see the threads and which one was failing.

Comment: We checked again - the only crashes we can find are older ones from the end of May. There are a lot of unknown ones without any date or time given, but they seem to come from some other apps.

Comment: Ok, then can you add some printouts to check when that crash happen? Does it happen when you open the app at a given moment, or after you perform some action?

Comment: We tried to add printouts. It happens after the bindings - when we bind the fields, the crash happens a few seconds after (~1.5 seconds). The printout directly after the bindings gets printed - and if no more code follows, the app crashes. Otherwise it waits until other code is processed and crashes right after.

Comment: I've used this service for a long time, without any issues. I'd suggest to do more tests, commenting out some code, reading only one key..., until you narrow down the issue.

Comment: We tried to narrow it down - it has to do with the strings we save beforehand. Gluon seems not to find them. - the true / false one work fine.
Can we have a look into the file that the settings service saves or get rid of it somehow?
Furthermore, we were not able to find a working settings example - would you mind sharing one with us? Maybe that helps narrow it down too.

Comment: I see in your log above: `firstName not found`. That comes from [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/88e9241187d5af416a553ed4f3c632c847caa228/plugins/plugin-settings/ios/src/main/native/Settings.m#lines-99). That means you didn't store any value for it in the first place? Anyway, the service is working (as booleans are retrieved), so something is wrong with the strings, not the service itself.You can check the [Tic tac toe](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/83f402a9ac077d7c0648e6ce16baeca34141b5a4/tic-tac-toe-client) sample.

Comment: Actually we did not, since it worked seamlessly with Android in the first place.
We also figured out, that the loading of the booleans did not work too...

Since we use properties, we need to figure out what the initial value of a SimpleStringProperty is.

Thank you for the example, we will try to make it work this way :)